# Nodejs program ruuning but front end not show on browser in google compute engine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using google compute engine ubuntu 20.04, apache2 and nodejs. I tried running nodejs using `pm2` or `nodemon`, and nodejs works as it should. but when I open it in my browser with `myipaddress:3000` / `mydomain.id`, it only says `This site can't be reached`. is there something wrong with my server settings? or google compute engine limit to access port 3000?

if I run `nodemon app.js`

```
[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server started on port 3000
```

below I also include the website config in my apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.id
    ServerName api.mydomain.id
    ServerAlias www.api.mydomain.id
    
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.mydomain.id [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.api.mydomain.id
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

please tell me how to solve this, I've spent a lot of time because of this problem.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have never changed anything with firewall configuration, Compute instances in your network are blocked port 3000 traffic inbound by default.

Check your network's firewall policy at VPC networks -> firewall page like below.

If you don't have the port 3000 inbound allow policy, you can make it on the same page.

[image]

Comment: I've added the port, now the frontend can be seen on the ipaddress, but it's still an error in my domain

Comment: For the domain issue, follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart) to configure cloud DNS. If the problem persists, provide more information about your domain and DNS set up with a screenshot of the command ‘dig <your domain>’.